# Equivalent to tar's "--strip-components=1" in unzip?

Tags: zip, tar, unzip

I have a script that extracts a tar.gz-file to a specified subdirectory *mysubfolder*:

```
mkdir mysubfolder; tar --extract --file=sourcefile.tar.gz --strip-components=1 --directory=mysubfolder;
```

Is there any equivalent way of doing this with a zip-file?

Comment: Just use bsdtar

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As Mathias said, `unzip` has no such option. But a one-liner bash script can do the job.

Problem is: the best approach depends on your archive layout. A solution that *assumes* a single top-level dir will fail miserably if the content is directly in the archive root: think about an archive containing `/a/foo`, `/b/foo`, `/foo`, and the chaos of stripping `/a` and `/b`.

And the same fail happens with `tar --strip-component`. There is no one-size-fits-all solution.

So, to strip the root dir, assuming there *is* one (and *only* one):

```
unzip -d "$dest" "$zip" && f=("$dest"/*) && mv "$dest"/*/* "$dest" && rmdir "${f[@]}"
```

Just make sure that second-level files/dirs do *not* have the same name of the top-level parent (for example, `/foo/foo`). But `/foo/bar/foo` and `/foo/bar/bar` are ok. If they do, or you just want to be safe, you can use a temp dir for extraction:

```
temp=$(mktemp -d) && unzip -d "$temp" "$zip" && mkdir -p "$dest" &&
mv "$temp"/*/* "$dest" && rmdir "$temp"/* "$temp"
```

If you're using Bash, you can test if top level is a single dir or not using:

```
f=("$temp"/*); (( ${#f[@]} == 1 )) && [[ -d "${f[0]}" ]] && echo "Single dir!"
```

Speaking of Bash, you should turn on `dotglob` to include hidden files, and you can wrap everything in a single, handy function:

```bash
# unzip featuring an enhanced version of tar's --strip-components=1
# Usage: unzip-strip ARCHIVE [DESTDIR] [EXTRA_cp_OPTIONS]
# Derive DESTDIR to current dir and archive filename or toplevel dir
unzip-strip() (
    set -eu
    local archive=$1
    local destdir=${2:-}
    shift; shift || :
    local tmpdir=$(mktemp -d)
    trap 'rm -rf -- "$tmpdir"' EXIT
    unzip -qd "$tmpdir" -- "$archive"
    shopt -s dotglob
    local files=("$tmpdir"/*) name i=1
    if (( ${#files[@]} == 1 )) && [[ -d "${files[0]}" ]]; then
        name=$(basename "${files[0]}")
        files=("$tmpdir"/*/*)
    else
        name=$(basename "$archive"); name=${archive%.*}
        files=("$tmpdir"/*)
    fi
    if [[ -z "$destdir" ]]; then
        destdir=./"$name"
    fi
    while [[ -f "$destdir" ]]; do destdir=${destdir}-$((i++)); done
    mkdir -p "$destdir"
    cp -ar "$@" -t "$destdir" -- "${files[@]}"
)
```

Now put that in your `~/.bashrc` and you'll never have to worry about it again. Simply use as:

```
unzip-strip sourcefile.zip [mysubfolder] [OPTIONS]
```

This little beast will:

- Create `mysubfolder` for you if it does not exist
- Automatically detect if if your zip archive contains a single top-level directory and handle the extraction accordingly.
- `mysubfolder` is *optional*. If blank it will extract to a subdir of the **current** directory (not necessarily the *archive* directory!), named after:

  - The single top-level directory in the archive, if there is one
  - or archive file name, without the (presumably `.zip`) extension
- If destination path, given or derived, already exists *as a file*, increment the name until a suitable one is found (new path or existing directory).
- By default this will:

  - be silent
  - overwrite any existing files
  - preserve links and attributes (mode, timestamps, etc)
- You can pass extra `OPTIONS` to `cp`. Useful options are:

  - `-v|--verbose`: output each copied file, just like `unzip` does
  - `-n|--no-clobber`: do not overwrite existing files
  - `-u|--update`: only overwrite files that are newer than the destination
- Such extra `OPTIONS` are the 3rd argument onward. Craft a proper argument parser if needed.
- It will use *double* the extracted disk space during the operation, due to "extract to temp dir and copy" approach. No way around this without losing some of its flexibility/features.

Comment: This will not unzip into an existing directory structure as I'd hoped (I tried to use . in place of mysubfolder). I ended up just unzipping (unzip zip-with-top-dir.zip) and then copying (cp -rv extracted-top-zip-dir/* .).

Comment: Your good design saved me from having to re-download 2 _big_ archives. I tarted in `zipsdir`. `$ ls` #output: `ar1.zip ar2.zip ar3.zip` ; `$ dest="."; thezip="ar1.zip"; unzip -qq -d "$dest" "$thezip" && f=("$dest"/*) && mv "$dest"/*/* "$dest" && rmdir "${f[@]}"` #output: `rmdir: failed to remove './ar1.zip': Not a directory` \n `rmdir: failed to remove './ar1_file1': Not a directory` \n `rmdir: failed to remove './ar2.zip': Not a directory` \n `rmdir: failed to remove './ar3.zip': Not a directory` ; #RESULT: `$ ls` #output: `ar1.zip ar1_file1 ar1_subdir1 ar1_subdir2 ar2.zip ar3.zip` Thx4 rmdir

Comment: @catgofire: now it does ;-)

Answer (score 13):

You can use `-j` to junk paths (do not make directories). This is only recommended for somewhat common single-level archives. Archives with multi level directory structures will be flattened - this might even lead to name clashes for the files to extract.

From the man page of unzip:

> ```
>    -j     junk  paths.   The  archive's directory structure is not recreated; all files are deposited in the
>           extraction directory (by default, the current one).
> ```

Comment: This answer would've been more useful to me if it also explained how to make it output stuff to a named directory instead of the current directory.

Answer (score 9):

As others have noted, unzip does not support this. However, bsdtar can extract zip files as well.

```
bsdtar xvf app.zip --strip-components=1 -C /opt/some-app
```

bsdtar can also extract streams (which unzip does not support).

```
curl -sSL https://... | bsdtar xvf - --strip-components=1 -C /opt/some-app
```

Comment: This is great, however there is a slight flaw in that `bsdtar` does not mark executables as executable, but `unzip` does. I tried `--fflags` and `--insecure` but it made no difference. Testing with [this zip](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/releases/download/z3-4.12.1/z3-4.12.1-x64-glibc-2.35.zip).

Answer (score 8):

I couldn’t find such an option in [the manual pages for `unzip`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?unzip), so I’m afraid this is impossible. :(

However, (depending on the situation) you could work around it. For example, if you’re sure the only top-level directory in the zip file is named `foo-` followed by a version number, you could do something like this:

```
cd /tmp
unzip /path/to/file.zip
cd foo-*
cp -r . /path/to/destination/folder
```

Comment: Nice approach, but a bit incomplete: you will still have foo* dir with the full extracted content.

Comment: Yes, I didn’t add `rm -rf foo-*` on purpose as that’s potentially dangerous. What if there already was a folder named `foo-bar`? Note that the extraction is being done within the `/tmp` folder, which gets emptied automatically every now and then.

Comment: That's why I chained operations using `&&`: a given step only happens if the previous step was successful, so the last one (the `rm`) only runs if *all* steps completed with no error.

Comment: That's also why one should never user `/tmp/some-hardcoded-folder-name` as a temp folder, but instead should use `mktemp` for that: it guarantees there will be no such existing folder. Check my answer below.